# Converting rows from text file into rows of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a text file:

1; (2,2); (3,3); (3,6); (4,8)

2; (2,1); (3,1); (4,1)

3; (6,2); (4,3); (3,1); (1,1)

4; (2,8); (3,8); (3,6); (4,2); (6,0)

5; (0,0); (3,3); (3,6); (4,2)

6; (1,1); (3,9)

My task is to convert each line into a tuple to calculate their length (I have the function for this made already.  My problem is that I don't know how to read it line by line instead of column by column.

Here is my code that I have so far but I dont know what to do next

```
with open('polyline.txt') as poly:
        for line in poly:
            temp_line = line.split(';')
            temp_line = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), temp_line)) # Removes '\n' from each line
            poly_tups = temp_line[1:]
            print(poly_tups)
```

Which returns:

['(2,2)', '(3,3)', '(3,6)', '(4,8)']

['(2,1)', '(3,1)', '(4,1)']

['(6,2)', '(4,3)', '(3,1)', '(1,1)']

['(2,8)', '(3,8)', '(3,6)', '(4,2)', '(6,0)']

['(0,0)', '(3,3)', '(3,6)', '(4,2)']

['(1,1)', '(3,9)']

but 'poly_tups' is now only = ['(1,1)', '(3,9)']

How can I form these into individual rows of tuples (left to right)? Think I have spent so much time looking that my mind has turned to mush.

EDIT: Appears I am confusing contributors with my intentions.

These ['(1,1)', '(3,9)'] are coordinates, so my task is to calculate the length of each line using these coordinates with (1,1) & (3,9) being (x,y).

Here is the function I have made

```
def polyline_length(tuple):
    #This function calculates the length of a polyline
    # Coordinates = x & y
    x, y = zip(*tuple)
    for i in range(len(tuple)):
        length = math.sqrt((x[i-1]-x[i])**2+(y[i-1]-y[i]**2))
        return length
```

So I need to be able to add each row to this function to return its length.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand completely what you ask but I assume you are trying to get every list's length. Can you check my code, if it doesn't help, please let me know

```
with open('polyline.txt') as poly:
    total = 0
    for line in poly:
        temp_line = line.split(';')
        temp_line = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), temp_line)) # Removes '\n' from each line
        poly_tups = temp_line[1:]
        print(poly_tups)

        if (len(poly_tups)) > 0:
            print(len(poly_tups))
            total += len(poly_tups)
    print("Total : " , total)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I am looking for each row as in: ['(2,2)', '(3,3)', '(3,6)', '(4,8)'] &
['(2,1)', '(3,1)', '(4,1)'] etc. to be made into tuples that can then be added to a function. The length is in relation to a polyline, and these are the coordinates. Apologies for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand correctly and i would have made this a comment instead (if only my reputation had allowed it), but do you mean to accumulate the lines?

```
result= []
with open('polyline.txt') as poly:
        for line in poly:
            temp_line = line.split(';')
            temp_line = list(map(lambda s: s.strip(), temp_line)) # Removes '\n' from each line
            poly_tups = temp_line[1:]
            result.append(poly_tups)

print(result)
```

Comment: Hi, apologies for the confusion. Each row is a list of coordinates ['(2,2)', '(3,3)', '(3,6)', '(4,8)'], in this case I am looking to add each row to a separate tuple, ['(2,1)', '(3,1)', '(4,1)'] ,['(6,2)', '(4,3)', '(3,1)', '(1,1)'] etc.